# Get is being stripped off an HTML form

Tags: html, forms, get

I have an HTML form on a page.  The method is POST, but I'm manually adding a GET parameter to the URL string depending on which button the user clicks.  But when the form is submitted, the GET is being stripped off the URL.

I'm really baffled by this.  This method has worked many times in the past, and *this actual form* itself used to work fine.  Suddenly, the exact same (formerly working) code doesn't work.

I'm using Firefox Web Developer tools to look at which parameters are passed in the request, and there's no sign of the GET.

```
<form method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="report" value="abc">
    ...a couple Select form fields...
    <input type="submit" action="reports.php?format=PDF" value="Go">
    [<input type="submit" action="reports.php?format=preview" value="Web Preview">]
</form>
```

Basically, if they click "Go" they should get a PDF, and if they click "Web Preview" they get the same report as a web page; but the "format" parameter isn't received on the processing end of things.

(I've also tried it in multiple browsers.)

**Edit to add:** I can confirm that the POST data is being received on the processing end. Only the GET is missing.

**Edit to add:**
If I move the action to the `<form>` tag, it works.  Of course that prevents me from having two buttons that do two things, so it doesn't solve the problem, but it's a clue to what might be happening.  This DOES work:

```
<form method="post" action="reports.php?format=PDF" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="report" value="abc">
    ...a couple Select form fields...
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
    <!-- [<input type="submit" action="reports.php?format=preview" value="Web Preview">] -->
</form>
```

Comment: Wondering if there's some weird Server setting that could do this -- especially as the code hasn't changed from when it worked. Running IIS 7

Comment: My first guess would be server side as well; second guess would be browser updates.  Do you know if the IIS box auto-updates?

Comment: A co-worker tested it in IE 8, (and I tested in Firefox and Chrome) so pretty sure it's not the browser.  The server does get updated from time to time, but not terrible often. But I also don't really know when this problem started/ Hmmm...

Comment: New info added to question. It appears to only happen if the "action" attribute is on the Submit button. Move it to the Form tag and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved -- In a submit `<input>`, an "action" attribute is invalid.  I should have used "formaction":

```
<input type="submit" formaction="reports.php?format=PDF" value="Go">
```

Somewhere along the way an update to various web browsers must have stopped accepting "action".

Answer (score 1):

The first place I would look would be to verify that the data is indeed being sent as a POST request.  If, for any reason, the browser thinks the form should be using a GET request, it will quite happily delete and replace the hardcoded query string.

What I would suggest is doing a var_dump() on $_POST and $_GET in reports.php to get a definitive idea of what the browser is actually transmitting.  There may be some clues in the output.

If the $_GET data is truly missing, I would then check to verify that no one has put a rewrite rule into place on the server to strip query strings off of PHP requests, or even requests to this specific page.  As far as I am aware IIS does not normally strip query strings from POST requests, as this would go against well established standards, but it is always possible that rules were manually added to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The POST data is indeed being passed

Comment: var_dump POST: array(3) { ["report"]=> string(3) "abc" ["pd_user"]=> string(3) "all" ["pd_period"]=> string(3) "139" } var_dump GET: array(0) { }